# Rails 3: DEPRECATION WARNING: config.action_view.debug_rjs will be removed in 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, warnings

When I run `rails s` I got the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: config.action_view.debug_rjs will be removed in 3.1, from 3
.1 onwards you will need to install prototype-rails to continue to use RJS templ
ates . (called from service at D:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserve
r.rb:111)
```

How could I avoid getting this warning ?

I use:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 3.0.9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `config.action_view.debug_rjs` setting from your environments in `config/environments`. By default it's only defined in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line in one of your `config/environments` files that references it.